# Power apps navigation

Tags: powerapp

I need to set a navigation condition:

If Label20 <16 navigate to screen3, if label20>16 navigate to screen 2.

Can anyone assist?

As always thanks a million!
jose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
If(Value(Label20.Text) < 16, Navigate( Screen3, ScreenTransition.Cover ), Value(Label20.Text) > 16, Navigate( Screen2, ScreenTransition.Cover ))
```

Comment: Rikking, 
on label20 i have text property selected:
formula:
Sum(Dropdown3.Selected.Value, Dropdown4.Selected.Value, Dropdown5.Selected.Value,Dropdown6.Selected.Value);If(Value(Label20.Text) < 16, Navigate( Screen3, ScreenTransition.Cover ), Value(Label20.Text) > 16, Navigate( Screen2, ScreenTransition.Cover )) 
Where am i going wrong?

Comment: The **sum()** method is Ok. The problem is that the Text property expects text and in the IF statement you're passing the **Navigate()** method. You could create a button and in the **OnSelect()** method add that IF statement. If that doesn't suit your needs pls try to explain what's the ideia behind the dropdowns, label...

Comment: Or you could do that when the last dropdown is changed, by going to the **OnChange()** method and paste `If(Value(Sum(Dropdown3.Selected.Value, Dropdown4.Selected.Value, Dropdown5.Selected.Value,Dropdown6.Selected.Value)) < 16, Navigate( Screen3, ScreenTransition.Cover ), Value(Sum(Dropdown3.Selected.Value, Dropdown4.Selected.Value, Dropdown5.Selected.Value,Dropdown6.Selected.Value)) > 16, Navigate( Screen2, ScreenTransition.Cover ))`

Comment: Rikking, the idea is, that there are 5 steps. You can only proceed to the next step if you score 16 or more. If not, the audit finishes and directs you to the action screen. If you score 16 more, it allows you to go to the next audit stage.